# Image folder access as URL in WebApi issue ..!

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have Image folder in hosted WEB API, while accessing image with URL "http://localhost:49245/images/abc.png" is working fine at local end, but not on hosted site at server. Showing "500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.”
 I have already added :

`<location path="Images">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>`

But still not working.
Please suggest.

Comment: Have you tried configuring your mime types in IIS?

Comment: Maybe you should switch to host on your local IIS instead of VS Development Server, then seeing if still any error.

Comment: yes haz, application is already on local IIS. Even on hosting , Image file is accessible at local server end but not on client system end.